# Time difference in hh:mm format

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am calculating the difference between two times with the following function:

```
const calcTimeDiff = (time1: string, time2: string) => {
    const timeStart = new Date()
    const timeEnd = new Date()
    const valueStart = time1.split(':')
    const valueEnd = time2.split(':')

    timeStart.setHours(+valueStart[0], +valueStart[1], 0, 0)
    timeEnd.setHours(+valueEnd[0], +valueEnd[1], 0, 0)

    const difference = timeEnd.getTime() - timeStart.getTime()
    return format(difference, 'HH:mm') // date-fns
}
```

For example `calcTimeDiff('08:45', '16:00')` which should yield `07:15`. However, I get `08:15` instead. My guess is that it is caused by timezone conflicts.

Debugging my code gave me the following insights:

```
console.log(difference, timeStart, timeEnd)
Thu Jan 01 1970 08:15:00 GMT+0100, Wed Aug 17 2022 08:45:00 GMT+0200, Wed Aug 17 2022 16:00:00 GMT+0200
```

Comment: You dont want the `new Date` in your `const difference`

Comment: I removed it but still yielding wrong result

Answer (score 1):

Why not make use of the `intervalToDuration` method which is included in the [date-fns library](https://date-fns.org/v2.29.1/docs/intervalToDuration). This will return an object for you like below

```
{years: 0, months: 0, days: 0, hours...}
```

It can be implemented easily into your function like so:

```
const calcTimeDiff = (time1: string, time2: string) => {
    const timeStart = new Date()
    const timeEnd = new Date()
    const valueStart = time1.split(':')
    const valueEnd = time2.split(':')

    timeStart.setHours(+valueStart[0], +valueStart[1], 0, 0)
    timeEnd.setHours(+valueEnd[0], +valueEnd[1], 0, 0)

    return intervalToDuration({ start: timeStart, end: timeEnd })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get string in `hh:mm` format, you don't need `Date`, just calculate:

```js
const calcTimeDiff = (time1: string, time2: string) => {
  const [h1, m1] = time1.split(':');
  const [h2, m2] = time2.split(':');
  let diff = (h2 - h1) * 60 + (m2 - m1);
  if (diff < 0) diff += 24 * 60;
  const hours = Math.floor(diff / 60);
  const minutes = diff - hours * 60;
  const hh = hours.toString().padStart(2, '0');
  const mm = minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0');
  return `${hh}:${mm}`;
}
```

Comment: Seems to complicated. I would prefer the original solution with the bug fixed

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @eugene anf thats the right way to go but in case you are looking for an answer in the format your code is written here is the code

```
const calcTimeDiff = (time1, time2) => {
    const timeStart = new Date()
    const timeEnd = new Date()
    const valueStart = time1.split(':')
    const valueEnd = time2.split(':')

    timeStart.setHours(+valueStart[0], +valueStart[1], 0, 0)
    timeEnd.setHours(+valueEnd[0], +valueEnd[1], 0, 0)

    let difference = new Date();
    difference.setHours(timeEnd.getHours() - timeStart.getHours())
    difference.setMinutes(timeEnd.getMinutes() - timeStart.getMinutes())
    return console.log(difference, timeStart, timeEnd) // date-fns
}
calcTimeDiff('08:45', '16:00');
```

In your code you are creating a date object using the difference in time which will lead you to a random time.

Answer (score -1):

Solved it this way:

```
const calcTimeDiff = (time1: string, time2: string) => {
    const timeStart = new Date()
    const timeEnd = new Date()
    const valueStart = time1.split(':')
    const valueEnd = time2.split(':')

    timeStart.setHours(+valueStart[0], +valueStart[1], 0, 0)
    timeEnd.setHours(+valueEnd[0], +valueEnd[1], 0, 0)

    const difference = new Date(timeEnd.getTime() - timeStart.getTime())

    return format(
        addMinutes(difference, difference.getTimezoneOffset()),
        'HH:mm'
    )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to perform what you want.

This can be done using the `diff` method.

```js
const calcTimeDiff = (time1, time2) => {
    
    const start = moment(time1, 'HH:mm');   
    const end = moment(time2, 'HH:mm');   
    
    let diff = end.diff(start);
    return moment.utc(diff).format("HH:mm");
}

console.log(calcTimeDiff("8:15", "16:15"))
console.log(calcTimeDiff("7:45", "19:21"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```